# How to get a specific element from a page to another using JS and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, getelementbyid

I need to build a script (fully JS, no jQuery allowed) that will perform some actions on a page, let's call it the Active page, based on data that are stored on a different page (same domain), call it the Passive page.

These data are stored in specific HTML elements in the Passive page.

I'm totally new to Ajax, so before starting out I tried to make research on the internet, but found nothing useful (or, maybe, nothing I could understand).

How can I retrieve the specific data I need?

I'm stuck with this little code, which however only returned me the page 'skeleton':

```
javascript:

var myAttempt = new XMLHttpRequest();
myAttempt.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myAttempt = this.responseText;
 }
}
myAttempt.open("GET", "https://www.website.com/passivepage.html", true);
myAttempt.send();
```

Where should I tell the script to look for a specific element of the Passive page?

Thanks

Comment: Google's tip: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your ajax request you receive a string as response, to find an specific element inside it you can create a dummy DOM element and add the string to it, then find every element you are looking for inside dummy element. like this:

```
var myAttempt = new XMLHttpRequest();
myAttempt.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.display = 'none';
    div.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    document.body.append(div);
    const theElement = div.querySelector('selector');
    alert(theElement.getAttribute('x'));
 }
}
myAttempt.open("GET", "/url", true);
myAttempt.send();
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this code, but seems I'm not able to get anything different from n theElement. If in the Passive page I have a <table classe="abc">, than in the above query selector I should write put ('.abc') to get It copied into theElement, shouldn't I? Seems like I'm missing something

Comment: did you receive right response by your ajax?

Comment: Well I received the message 'DevTools failed to load source map' in fact, and when I click on the following link I see error 404

Comment: Besides that everything looks fine with the Ajax response though

Comment: remove `div.style.display = 'none';` and check does it append passive page content to `theElement` successfully or not

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it does not change the outcome

Comment: are you sure your code passes `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)` ? get a console.log of your response and seet the response in browser console

Comment: Hmm maybe I found the issue: the data I need are not static and are processed in the Passive page when It gets opened, but the ajax response I get shows only the page itself 'before' data processing. I can refer in the selector to IDs or classes that belongs to 'root' items of the page, but I can't get the processed ones as they seem to 'exist' at a later stage. Do you know if there Is a way to obtain such data in the Ajax response? Thanks again

Comment: It's really depends on the project, but in general I think it's better to implement a backend api and fetch data by requesting to the api.